# Prononciation du mot "parc"

Tags: prononciation

Pourquoi faut-il prononcer le "c" terminal en le mot "parc"?  Est-ce que "parc" se derive du mot anglais "park" (ou le "k" terminal se prononce?)

Comment: Lorsque vous posez une question il faut d'abord faire certaines vérifications de base et les mentionner dans le texte de votre question en expliquant pourquoi ce que vous avez trouvé n'est pas suffisant ; dans le cas de la présente question, la première des choses à faire est de vérifier l'étymologie du mot « parc » (un bon dictionnaire pour faire cela : CNRTL (Trésor de la langue Française)).

Comment: Quand il s'agit de mots antérieur au 20eme siècle, c'est presque toujours le mot anglais qui vient du mot français, ou bien les deux mots qui proviennent directement du Latin.

Answer (score 1):

Réglons d'abord la question de l'étymologie : « parc » en français vient du latin *parricus* et le mot anglais *parc* (*park*) a été introduit en Angleterre avec l'invasion normande (Hastings, 1066). Donc le voyage s'est fait dans le sens France → Angleterre.

Je ne suis pas spécialiste de l'évolution phonétique de la langue, mais sachant que les voyelles étant moins stables que les consonnes dans le processus d'évolution de la prononciation, je soupçonne que la syllabe finale a disparu ainsi que le *i*.
Par ailleurs il faut constater que la prononciation de la consonne finale en français n'a rien d'étonnant. Le « l » final se prononce presque toujours, le « q » et le « k » finaux se prononcent toujours, quant au « c » final parfois il se prononce comme dans : sac, truc, avec, parc, etc... parfois il ne se prononce pas : estomac, porc, tronc, etc...

Comment: On pensera aussi au prénom Marc dont le C ce prononce, sauf quand il s'agit d'une célèbre place vénitienne ou d'un nettoyant pour carrelage.

Comment: @XouDo > Ou du marc de café...